# Stop insert after invalid validation

Tags: c#, sql-server, c#-4.0

I want to stop insert into the Database after a invalid validation. Like the following code snippet shows the message for invalid phone number but still it inserts the code into Database. One more question, I want to apply this rule on whole of my program which I think has this potential bug.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$");

            if (regexObj.IsMatch(textBox3.Text))
            {
                string formattedPhoneNumber =
                    regexObj.Replace(textBox3.Text, "($1) $2-$3");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Phone Number! \nFormat is (XXX) XXX-XXXX");
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) || textBox1.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Field can't be left blank!");
                return;
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text) || textBox2.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Name for the Author!");
                return;
            }

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server = DAFFODILS-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Library;Trusted_Connection=True;");
            SqlCommand sql1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT into Members VALUES('" + textBox1.Text + "' , '" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "')", con);
            con.Open();
            sql1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            this.membersTableAdapter.Fill(this.booksDataSet.Members);
            MessageBox.Show("Data Added!");
            textBox1.Text = "";
            textBox2.Text = "";
            textBox3.Text = "";
            textBox1.Focus();

        }
    }
```

I think, I have to use a method for this but I don't know how. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your program has a SQL injection issue.  Google "SQL injection" and then fix the problem with a parameterized query or you will be in for a world of hurt.

Comment: I am not concerned about that. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of these things isn't like the others:

```
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Phone Number! \nFormat is (XXX) XXX-XXXX");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) || textBox1.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Field can't be left blank!");
            return;
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text) || textBox2.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Name for the Author!");
            return;
        }
```

Notice how two of the validations have a `return` right after the `MessageBox.Show`? Those are the ones that return from the method without inserting the record. Notice how the phone-number validation doesn't have the `return`? That's why it shows the message and then inserts anyway -- because that's what you told it to do. You never told it to stop after showing the message; you just let it continue running the rest of the method, which consists mainly of the INSERT.

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning if the phone number is invalid but continuing in your method.  Without restructuring what you're doing too much, I would probably do it thusly so all fields go through validation rather than fail the first time one fails:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> validationErrors = new List<string>();

        Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$");

        if (regexObj.IsMatch(textBox3.Text))
        {
            string formattedPhoneNumber =
                regexObj.Replace(textBox3.Text, "($1) $2-$3");
        }
        else
        {
            validationErrors.Add("Invalid Phone Number! \nFormat is (XXX) XXX-XXXX");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) || textBox1.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            validationErrors.Add("Field can't be left blank!");
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text) || textBox2.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            validationErrors.Add("No Name for the Author!");
        }

        if (validationErrors.Count > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, validationErrors.ToArray()));
            return;
        }

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server = DAFFODILS-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Library;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        SqlCommand sql1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT into Members VALUES('" + textBox1.Text + "' , '" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "')", con);
        con.Open();
        sql1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        this.membersTableAdapter.Fill(this.booksDataSet.Members);
        MessageBox.Show("Data Added!");
        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox2.Text = "";
        textBox3.Text = "";
        textBox1.Focus();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only checking for errors and displaying error messages.

Intialize a variable hasAnyError with a value of false at the beginning.. and set it to true in those "if" blocks.. and put that Sql block in the end like below :

```
if (!hasAnyError) { 
    //put all that sql block here 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not stopping the program flow. You need to stop the method immediately after when you display the message box. To do this, simply add this after every MessageBox that displays the error:

```
return;
```

e.g:

```
MessageBox.Show("Invalid Phone Number! \nFormat is (XXX) XXX-XXXX");
return;
```